# If $S = A \times B$ with $|A| \ne |B|$ and both cyclic, and $S \in \mbox{Syl}_3(G)$, then $G$ has a normal $3$-complement

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group of odd order, and let $S$ be a Sylow $3$-subgroup of $G$. Assume that $S$ is abelian with $S = A \times B$ and $A,B$ cyclic. If $|A| \ne |B|$, then from Burnside's transfer theorem if follows that $G$ has a normal $3$-complement.

To apply [Burnside's transfer theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_p-complement), we must have 
\begin{align*}
 N_G(S) \le C_G(S) & \Leftrightarrow S \le Z(N_G(S)) = C_G(N_G(S)) \cap N_G(S) \\ & \Leftrightarrow [S, N_G(S)] = 1.
\end{align*}
But I do not see that this follows if $|A| \ne |B|$? Why does Burnside's transfer theorem is applicable here?

Comment: That's because the only primes that divide $|{\rm Aut}(S)|$ are $2$ and $3$. But that's true even when $|A| = |B|$, so you don't need that assumption.

Comment: @DerekHolt How you see this? In know that for a cyclic group $H$ we have $|\mbox{Aut}(H)| = \varphi(|H|)$, hence $|\mbox{Aut}(A)| = p^{n-1}(p-1)$ and $|\mbox{Aut}(B)| = p^{m-1}(p-1)$ with $p = 3$ and $|A| = p^n, |B| = p^m$. Also $\mbox{Aut}(A) \times \mbox{Aut}(B) \le \mbox{Aut}(A \times B)$, but we do not have equality until $A,B$ are characteristic, so I see that $2$ and $3$ are possible divisors, but not that they are the only divisors?

Comment: $S$ has a characteristic series is which factors have order $3$ or $3^2$. The only primes dividing $|{\rm GL}(2,3)|$ and $|{\rm GL}(1,3)|$ are $2$ and $3$. Also, automorphisms of $p$-group that centralize each factor is an invariant series have order a power of $p$.

Comment: @DerekHolt You mean $S / \Phi(S)$ has order $3$ or $3^2$ ($1 < \Phi(S) < S$ with Frattini subgroup is the characteristic series you are talking about?), and as it is elementary abelian its automorphism group is $\mbox{GL}(1,3)$ or $\mbox{GL}(2,3)$. If $|S / \Phi(S)| = 3$, then $S$ is cyclic and hence its automorphism group has order $p^{k-1}(p-1)$, but what if $|S / \Phi(S)| = 9$; I do not see how the statements about the automorphisms of this quotient take over to $S$?

Comment: Sorry but I do not have time now to explain this in any more detail. In general, if $S$ is the direct product of two cyclic $p$-groups with $p$ an odd prime, then $|{\rm Aut}(S)|$ is divisible only by primes $q \le p$. (When $p=2$ it is divisible only by $2$ and $3$.) You could ask about that as a separate question.

Comment: I did, see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1605512/if-g-is-the-direct-product-of-two-cyclic-p-groups-what-is-implied-for-the-o